# Click event multiplying after each AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with this section on my website:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function loadContent(val){
    $(".gallery").load(val, function(){
    console.log("Loaded");
  });
}

$(".Javascript").click(function(){
  loadContent("Javascript.html");
});

$(".JQuery").click(function(){
 loadContent("JQuery.html");
});

$(".HTML").click(function(){
 loadContent("HTML-CSS.html");
});

$(".APIs").click(function(){
  loadContent("APIs.html")
});

$(".Angular").click(function(){
 loadContent("Angular.html")
  });
});
```

Basically, every time I click on a link, I bring a new HTML file with a gallery of images in it with the load() function. But looking at the console, everytime I do a click, the number of GETs is doubled, this is what appears on the console:

XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8888/script.js."

How can I prevent this multiplying and what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct. May be you include this script twice? Or may be you have two `.gallery` blocks?
Try to write it inline in HTML inside  tag. Does it help?

Comment: I had a <script> tag at the end of every new HTML file that I called. Removing it fixes the multiplying issue, but...Breaks everything else.

Comment: Make a plunker with your problem please

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `.load(url)` will also include and execute the scripts that are inside the requested HTML by default. By specifying a selector, the scripts will be excluded.

An example:

```
// Load article.html with scripts:
$( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );

// Load article.html#content without scripts:
$( "#b" ).load( "article.html #content" );
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, literally adding "#content"? It displays nothing then.

Comment: No, only the section you want to load into your page (by ID or class).

Answer (score 0):

The solution after all was to add .off() on every click function:

```
$(".Javascript").off('click').click(function(){
  loadContent("Javascript.html")
});
```